# Encoded picture to Byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I'm running an xml request to get Item Picture in Quickbooks POS and it returns this response:

```
string response = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<QBPOSXML>
    <QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
        <ItemInventoryPicturesQueryRs requestID="912873739" statusCode="0" statusMessage="Status OK" statusSeverity="Info">
            <ItemInventoryPicturesRet>
                <ListID>5523943659390533889</ListID>
                <ItemInventoryPicture>
                    <EncodedPicture>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAAAAAAAD...</EncodedPicture>
                    <PictureName></PictureName>
                </ItemInventoryPicture>
            </ItemInventoryPicturesRet>
        </ItemInventoryPicturesQueryRs>
    </QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
</QBPOSXML>
```

and I want to save the encoded picture section as a jpg file, I tried this approach but it didn't work at all!

```
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
  System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
  return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}

//imageCode is the value of the EncodedPicture element in the xml
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\image.jpg",StrToByteArray(imagecodes));
```

[image: base64]

This is a base64 of the image above

```
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
```

Comment: Define `Didn't work at all`, do you get any error?

Comment: The code in the question does not work because there is no base64 decoding,

Comment: You must convert this base64 image to the desired `jpg` format

Comment: Do we really need the full base64 string in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect very few JPEG files are also printable ASCII text.

It seems much more likely that the content of `EncodedPicture` is a base64-representation of the data - which is confirmed by the text at the bottom of your question.

So assuming you've already extracted the value of the `EncodedPicture` element as a string, you just want `Convert.FromBase64String`:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\image.jpg", Convert.FromBase64String(imagecodes));
```

Comment: As a former ANSI artist I object to that :-)

Comment: @Trey: Just for you, I've made the first sentence more specific :)